# Leet Code 242. Valid Anagram KeyError: u'a'

Tags: python, keyerror

I'm doing [Leet Code 242: Valid Anagram](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-anagram/). I'm looking at a NeetCode solution from [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9UtInBqnCgA&ab_channel=NeetCode).
I'm trying to run and see what happened in the following code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def isAnagram(self, s, t):
if len(s) != len(t):
            return False
        CountS, CountT = {}, {}

        for i in range(len(s)):
            CountS[s[i]] == 1 + CountS.get(s[i],0)
            CountT[t[i]] == 1 + CountT.get(t[i],0)
        for c in hashS:
            if hashS[c] != hashT.get(c, 0):
                return False
        return True
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
KeyError: u'a'
    CountS[s[i]] == 1 + CountS.get(s[i],0)
Line 18 in isAnagram (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().isAnagram(param_1, param_2)
Line 67 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 77 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Comment: Do you have a question? What is it?

Comment: `CountS[s[i]] == 1 + CountS.get(s[i],0)` Because you have a double equal sign `==` here, this is doing a _comparison_, not an _assignment_.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues (mostly typos) with your implementation. After the first for loop, instead of assigning new entries to the hashmaps, you are actually comparing whether that key in the hashmap is equal to 1 + CountS.get(s[i],0) or 1 + CountT.get(t[i],0).

Replace the following:

```
CountS[s[i]] == 1 + CountS.get(s[i],0)
CountT[t[i]] == 1 + CountT.get(t[i],0)
```

with this:

```
CountS[s[i]] = 1 + CountS.get(s[i],0)
CountT[t[i]] = 1 + CountT.get(t[i],0)
```

This would help you get rid of the current key error that you are facing. However, you'll run into another error as you have some typos in the second for loop and indentation error in the if statement. Following is the corrected code (original solution from Neetcode):

```
class Solution:
    def isAnagram(self, s: str, t: str) -> bool:
    
        if len(s) != len(t):
            return False
    
        countS, countT = {}, {}
    
        for i in range(len(s)):
            countS[s[i]] = 1 + countS.get(s[i], 0)
            countT[t[i]] = 1 + countT.get(t[i], 0)
        
        for c in countS:
            if countS[c] != countT.get(c, 0):
               return False
    
        return True
```

Answer (score -1):

I created a much simpler approach:

```
class Solution:
    def isAnagram(self, s: str, t: str) -> bool:
        if sorted(list(s)) == sorted(list(t)):
            return True
        else: 
            return False
```

It works by creating lists from the strings `s` and `t` and then sorting them. After that both lists are compared and if they match they return `True` and if they don't they return `False`.

Comment: And even more simply: `return sorted(s) == sorted(t)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).